# Cassandra - What's the relation between 'start_rpc' and 'rpc_address' in cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra

I'm using cassandra 3.6.

The names seem to implying me that I need to enable `start_rpc` before set `rpc_address`.

I try disable `start_rpc` and set `rpc_address` to my local network address `192.168.201.144` ,my cluster is still working but I need to use `CQLSH_HOST=192.168.201.144 apache-cassandra-3.6/bin/cqlsh`  in order to connect to cassandra.

What's the relation between them?

Comment: I thought RPC (Thrift) had been removed in 3.x :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start rpc service, you need modify them together:

```
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 192.168.XXX.XXX
```

Rpc_address is the listen address for client connections (Thrift RPC service and native transport).Valid values are:

#### unset:

Resolves the address using the hostname configuration of the node. If left unset, the hostname must resolve to the IP address of this node using /etc/hostname, /etc/hosts, or DNS.

#### 0.0.0.0:

Listens on all configured interfaces, but you must set the broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than
0.0.0.0.

#### IP address

#### hostname